# Get the errors in hidden field value in django

Tags: jquery, django

index.html

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>index</title>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function(){
                alert($("errormsg").attr("value"));
            });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
         {% if  form.emailid.errors %}
              <input type="text" id="errormsg" value="{{ form.emailid.errors }}"/>
         {% endif %}
         {{ form.emailid }}
    </body>
</html>
```

models.py

```
class userdetails(models.Model):
     emailid=models.CharField(max_length=500)
```

forms.py

```
class new_register(ModelForm):
    emailid=forms.CharField(widget=forms.TextInput())

class Meta:
    model=userdetails

def clean_emailid(self):
    rcvd_mailid = self.cleaned_data.get('emailid')
    if rcvd_mailid:
        user_qs = userdetails.objects.filter(emailid = rcvd_mailid)
        qs_count=user_qs.count()
        if qs_count >= 1:
            raise forms.ValidationError("* Mail Id Already Exists")
    return self.cleaned_data['emailid'][:100]
```

views.py

```
def register_view(request, template_name="index.html"):
    if request.method=="POST": 
       user_values=new_register(data=request.POST)
       if user_values.is_valid():
           user_values.save()
           return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse("url_indexpage"))
       else:
           return render(request, template_name,{'form':user_values})
    elif request.method=="GET":
       user_values=new_register()
       return render(request, template_name,{'form':user_values})
```

I'm getting the error message in paragraph tag, but I can't able to get the error message in hidden field. Its getting as undefined. Is this any thing wrong? Any one can help? please!

Comment: you forgot the `#` and can use `.val()` - `alert($("#errormsg").val());`

Comment: you have misspelt `function` in `document.ready`

Comment: i tried .val also, but its alerting ""undefined.

Comment: i corrected the spelling, still i'm getting "undefined"

Comment: Then please update the question to reflect the current state of your code.